# Microsoft SSMS Error: The database was backed on a server running version 15.00.2080 which is incompatible with this server running version 14.00.1000

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm attempting to restore a database to Microsoft SQL Server (SSMS)  however I'm getting an error

> The database was backed on a server running version 15.00.2080 which is incompatible with my server which is running version 14.00.1000

However my server is updated and I still have the same issue. Any idea what's wrong?

[image: version 15 of server]

[image: Error]

Comment: SQL Sever Management Studio and the Server itself are completely different things.  SSMS is just the client application on your local computer that you use to communicate with the Server.  That you have SSMS version 15 is coincidence and also irrelevant.  The fact is that the Backup was from a ***Server*** of Version 15 *(Also Known As SQL Server 2019)*, and you're trying to restore it to a ***Server*** which is Version 14 *(Also Known As SQL Server 2017)*.  You need restore that backup on to a Version 15 Server.